# Erro: não é possível localizar nem carregar a classe principal

Tags: java, compilação

Estou em busca da solução do seguinte problema, faço um "OláMundo" no Netbeans e ele está compilando, faço ou outro no Bloco de Notas e no Notepad++, consigo criar a class com o javac Oi.java, mas quando coloco java Oi, aparece o seguinte erro:

> "Erro: não é possível localizar nem carregar a classe principal Oi"

OBS: Todos os fóruns que busco fala sobre a configuração da JAVA_HOME, da PATH e da CLASSPATH, todas já foram acertadas, quando coloco para mostrar no Prompt a versão ela aparece normalmente...

Como posso solucionar isso, como consigo rodar no Prompt?

Segue prints abaixo da pasta, do bloco de notas, do prompt e do teste rodando normalmente no Netbeans:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Edite a pergunta e poste sua classe

Comment: Postei o código básico de teste...

Está na pasta o arquivo Oi.java e o Oi.class

Comment: Quem negativou nao entende nada de java ou nao entendeu a pergunta, porque o problema aqui nao tem a ver com codigo e a imagem é válida pra entender o problema.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Provavelmente você está tentando rodar a classe sem compilar. É preciso compilar o arquivo .java antes:

```
javac Oi.java
```

para depois executar:

```
java Oi
```

Veja, a classe está funcionando normalmente:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

> Obs.: Certifique-se de que a classe tenha o mesmo nome do arquivo, se a classe se chama `MinhaClasse`, o arquivo também deve se chamar `MinhaClasse.java`.

No print, seu arquivo se chama *Oi.java*, mas a assinatura da classe esta com nome diferente(`public class Oie`)

> Obs<sup>2</sup>.: Se tiver informação de package na classe, o compilador vai procurar por essas pastas, e como não vai encontrar vai dar esse erro. Remova a informaçao de package a nao ser que possua hierarquia de pastas do package.

---

Tente também com o comando abaixo, onde a jvm vai forçar o classpath como a pasta atual e procurar a classe apenas dentro dela:

```
java -cp . Oi
```

[Nesta resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18093929/5524514) e [nesta outra do SOEn](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29331827/5524514) tem explicações mais detalhadas sobre os motivos que podem ocasionar esse problema.

Comment: Ok, muito obrigada mesmo!!! :)